# Symfony 3.2 ldap authentication issue

Tags: symfony, ldap

I am trying to authenticate users through ldap (window active directory) with Symfony 3.2 configured the service and security as per the [documents](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html)

But I am getting the error:

> php.DEBUG: Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"/var/www/html/workflow/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/Adapter/ExtLdap/Connection.php\",\"line\":54})"} []

Tried many changes in the parameters like adding the domain{username}
or copying the cn string completely from ldap search softerra.

`security.yml`:

```
security:
    providers:
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: ldap
                base_dn: dc=example,dc=example
                search_dn: "cn=user.name,DC=example,DC=example" 
                search_password: PassWord
                default_roles: ROLE_ADMIN
                uid_key: sAMAccountName

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        # an`enter code here`onymous: ~`enter code here`
        http_basic_ldap:
            service: ldap
            dn_string: 'uid={username},dc=example,dc=example' 

access_control:
   - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

`service.yml`:

```
    services:
        ldap:
            class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient
            arguments:
                - ip   # host
                - portenter code here         # port
                - 3           # version
                - false       # SSL
                - false       # TLS
```

`native php`:

```
<?php
$name = 'username@domain.local';
$pass = 'password';
$adServer = 'ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234/';

$basedn="OU=Users,OU=Office,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"
$filter="(&(!(ou=NoSync))(department=*)(sn=*))";

$attributes=array("displayname", "mail", "company", "department", "physicaldeliveryofficename", "memberOf","givenname","sn","manager",
                    "mobile", "ipphone", "telephoneNumber", "facsimiletelephonenumber", "streetaddress", "l", "st","userprincipalname",
                    "postalcode", "c", "title", "samaccountname", "useraccountcontrol");

$cnx = ldap_connect($adServer) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
ldap_bind($cnx, $name, $pass);

ldap_set_option($cnx, LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT,10000);
ldap_set_option($cnx, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die ("Could not set ldap protocol");;
ldap_set_option($cnx, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0) or die ("Could not set option referrals");
ldap_control_paged_result($cnx, 1000) or die ("Could not set option page limit");


$pageSize = 900;
    $total='';
    $cookie = '';
    $arr_rec=[];
    $arr_rec_update=[]; 
     do {
            $total = $pageSize + $total;
            ldap_control_paged_result($cnx, $pageSize, true, $cookie);

            $result  = ldap_search($cnx,$basedn,$filter,$attributes);
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($cnx, $result);
?>
```

Comment: by the way the users i am trying to authenticate they get successfully authenticated if i use native php ldap script.

Comment: Can you show us the php script you are using with native php ? It may help to spot the configuration issue.

Comment: hi thank you for offering the help

Comment: is "portenter code here" ok in your code ? replaces by real value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, declaring the ldap service as you did is deprecated, for Symfony 3.2 you should declare it using the ldap class:

`app/config/services.yml`:

```yml
services:
    ldap:
        class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
        factory: [ 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap', 'create']
        arguments:
            - ext_ldap
            - host: ip
            - port: 1234
            - version: 3
            - ssl: false
            - tls: false
```

Regarding the PHP script you provided, your configuration should look like this:

`app/config/security.yml`:

```yml
security:
    providers:
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: ldap
                base_dn: 'OU=Users,OU=Office,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx'
                search_dn: 'username@domain.local'
                search_password: 'password'
                default_roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic_ldap:
                service: ldap
                dn_string: '{username}'
                #dn_string: 'domain\{username}' # or try including your domain prefix
```

Comment: You're welcome, I have struggled with it quiet a lot of time! Glad to hear it helped you save some. ;)

Comment: indeed , whenever it comes to ldap and active directory it is kind of struggle. but it is clear that you are an expert. thanks again.